# Django - can not get a time function (timezone, datetime) to work properly, Getting ErrorName message: global name not defined

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, timezone

I'm a Django newbie,

I am following a tutorial and I had to create two models shown below:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

The following code is from the tutorial. I should get True.

```
# Make sure our custom method worked.
>>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> p.was_published_recently()
True
```

But when I type (same lines as tutorial):

```
>>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> p.was_published_recently()
```

I get the following error message:

```
models.py line 12 in was_published_recently
NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined..
```

I imported `datetime` and `timezone`... I don't see why I get that error message.

Any help will be appreciated! :-)

Comment: What happens if you enter `import datetime` in a Python command prompt? And which Python version is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't reproduce the problem, your code works for me.
You could try with something like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta as tdelta
...
def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - tdelta(days=-1)
```

Comment: Ok, sorry didn't see your comment in time. Glad it's working now.

Answer (score 11):

> You need to import Timezone first from Django utils and after that you need to import datetime.

```
from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    import datetime
```

Comment: Exactly correct.  I had the same error as the original poster - following the same default django tutorial (Part 1).  Your recommendation solved the problem.  Now, how do we get the tutorial updated to reflect this?

Answer (score 5):

In the tests tutorial (part 5), we work on the **polls/tests.py** file.  However, when you run the test, the error complains about the **polls/models.py** file.  This file isn't mentioned in the tests tutorial but you can see it in the error message.

Add `from django.utils import timezone` to the **polls/models.py** and try the test again.

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is about **Writing your first Django app, part 5**, you should add these two lines

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarification this is what I needed to add at the top of my polls/models.py file:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread.  I had the same problem because I forgot to add this line: 
from django.utils import timezone

Answer (score 0):

About that error message, please note what Django docs say:

> If you encounter an exception querying dates or times, please try installing it before filing a bug. >It’s as simple as:

`$ sudo pip install pytz`

Once you install the package, the problem will magically go away!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the things but the problem was still not getting solved. In the end the test worked when I also imported in the same order as mentioned by other in the shell too.

I had to import datetime in the end and only after that it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.

I found out that the Python shell must be reopened after adding import of `timezone` so the changes would be applied. After that it worked for me.